# Why background-color is not working on heading and lists inside span?

Tags: html, css, colors, background-color, styling

Background-color is applied on the content written in second span but not on first span having headings and list.
color is applied on both first and second span.

Why?

```css
span {
  background-color: aqua;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
1:

<span>
    <h2>Pointers for block</h2>
    <ol>
        <li>Width of a block level element is 100% of the viewport width.</li>
        <li>Height of a block isn't set by default.</li>
        <li>Height and width can be explicitly set using CSS.</li>
    </ol>
    <h2>Pointers for inline</h2>
    <ol>
        <li>Width of an inline level element is dependent on the content.</li>
        <li>Height of an inline isn't set by default.</li>
        <li>Height and width can't be explicitly set using CSS</li>
    </ol>
</span> 2:

<span>Hello</span>
```

Comment: use a div not a span

Comment: Use [a validator](https://validator.nu/). Span elements are not permitted h2 or ol children.

Answer (score 1):

I think part of the issue is that it is not 100% semantically correct for span elements to have certain types of children. As others have pointed out, the optimal solution probably is to replace <span> with <div>, or a similarly appropriate tag. However, if this is not possible or desirable, there are a few work-arounds you could implement:

First, I believe the issue is that the span's 'background-color' style rule is not being inherited by its children (the Mozilla docs have a good description of how some styles are inherited by default and others aren't [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance)).

You can work around this either by enforcing 'background-color' to be inherited by the span's children:

```
  span {
    background-color: aqua;
    color: red;
  }

  span * {
    background-color: inherit;
  }
```

Or by explicitly targeting the span’s children using the CSS child selector:

```
  span, span > * {
    background-color: aqua;
    color: red;
  }
```

Again, replacing your span tags is probably going to be the better / simpler solution, but the above should work in a pinch.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use `<div>` not span for the first one